# sql group by only one column

Tags: sql, linq

I have read many answers, but don't find my answer. How can i group my table in sql by only one column "Code"? my table:

```
 Name  Code quantity storename  
 name1 12345 1       A1  
 name1 12345 3       A2  
 name2 9009  40      A1  
 name2 9009  5       A3  
 name3 4004  3       A1
```

I want to see

```
 Name  Code  quantity storename  
 name1 12345 4        A1  
 name2 9009  45       A1 

 name3 4004  3        A1
```

Comment: But the result you want is not grouped. You have two rows for `name1`, even if you group by `Code`. How did you decide to only keep the one with `storename A1` instead of the one with the `storename A2`?

Comment: Why do you want to get those results? What criteria? Looks like group by name, code, sum qty, min store but can't be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (change the order if it is important):

```
SELECT NAME
     , SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY
     , code
     , storename
FROM   example
GROUP  BY NAME
          , code
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing would be

```
Select Name,
Code,
Sum(Quantity) as Quantity
Min(Storename) as Storename
From MyTable

Group by Name, Code
```

What is your logic on storename? I assumed the lowest (first value)

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select Name,  Code, count(quantity) asquantity,  storename  from tablename
group by Code,Name,storename
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the desired output for the shown input.

```
SELECT min(name) name,
       code,
       sum(quantity) quantity,
       min(storename) storename
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY code;
```

But it's another question if this is useful. Name probably is dependent of code? (Like `code` is the ID and `name` is the name of a product?) If it is, we won't have a problem there. But summing the quantity from all stores but only associating it with one store, is probably misleading. The store in the result doesn't necessarily have the quantity in the result in stock.

Comment: can i do it in linq?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how you want to rollup the non-grouped fields within the group and then place aggregations on them.

For example, you have two stores in your dataset that are tied to the same code. If you grouped by code then you would have to pick how the stores are presented when rolled up, generally a max or min would be used. However, you may need to include Store in your grouping as it seems like a pretty important entity. I'll show you two examples one with store in the grouping and one with it being aggregated.

With quantity rolled up at the Code level.

```
SELECT
   Name,
   Code,
   CodeQuantity = SUM(Qauntity),
   MaxStore = MAX(StoreName)
FROM
   MyTable
GROUP BY
   Name,
   Code
```

With quantity rolled up at the store level.

```
SELECT
   Name,
   Code,
   StoreName,
   StoreQuantity = SUM(Qauntity)
FROM
   MyTable
GROUP BY
   Name,
   Code,
   StoreName
```